# Способ разбить массив из сохраненного списка

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, массивы, jquery-ui

В общем ситуация такова,  Имеется две формы, первая форма позволяет пользователю с помощью `checkbox` выбрать количество процессов. Вторая, позволяет пользователю присвоить каждому процессу элементы, используя `jquery-drag` и `jquery-drop`. Проблема в том, что после присвоения элементов для каждого процесса я хочу распечатать полученные элементы, рассортированные для каждого процесса. Добавленный [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ny1n9gm0/1/) является примером лишь с двумя строками процессов. После нажатия кнопки 'сохранить' я получаю одну строку с сохраненным списком, но мне нужно чтобы это было две разные строки для каждого из процессов. Вот код, с `loop`:

```
        <label><?php for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
                    {
                        echo "<div class='proc'> <pre>";
                        echo "Process: ".$proc[$y]."      ";
                        echo "People required: ".$num[$y]."     ";  
                        echo "<span class='assigned' name='assigned[]' >People Assigned: </span><br /></pre>";  
                ?>
                <div class="procLeader">
                <label>Leader:</label>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content">
                    <div class="procleader">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="placeholder" name="procleader[]" <?php if (isset($procleader)) echo 'value="'.$procleader.'"' ?>>Add Process Leader here</li>
                            <input type="hidden" name="procleader[]" class="hiddenListInput3" />
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="procChecker">
                <label>Checker:</label>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content">
                    <div class="procchecker">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="placeholder" name="procchecker[]" <?php if (isset($procchecker)) echo 'value="'.$procchecker.'"' ?>>Add Process Checker here</li>
                            <input type="hidden" name="procchecker[]" class="hiddenListInput4" />
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prodStuff">
                <label>Stuff:</label>
                    <div class="ui-widget-content">
                    <div class="prodstuff">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="placeholder" name="prodstuff[]" <?php if (isset($prodstuff)) echo 'value="'.$prodstuff.'"' ?>>Add Stuff here</li>
                            <input type="hidden" name="prodstuff[]" class="hiddenListInput5" />
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php       
                    echo "</div>";                      
                    }
                ?>
        </label>
```

Comment: Попробуйте перефразировать свой вопрос. Очень сложно понять, в чем ваша проблема. "цикл сохраненных объектов" - лучше говорите массив или список объектов.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Bagackiy Несколько раз прочитал, но все равно ничего не понял... У Вас с чем проблема?! С PHP. JavaScript, jQuery или jQueryUI?!

Comment: @koks_rs Прошу прощения если непонятно описал проблему. Исправил пост, можете посмотреть еще раз.

Comment: @XelaNimed Прошу прощения если непонятно описал проблему. Исправил пост, можете посмотреть еще раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд Вам нужно переписать Ваш код, но это мое сугубо личное мнение, которое может не совпадать с суровой действительностью. Конкретно по теме:

```
    var LISTOBJ = {
        saveList: function() {

            // Выбираем все элементы с классом "proc" и проходим по ним циклом.
            $(".proc").each(function() {

              // В этот массив будем помещать текст из li-элементов.
              // Массив будет "заново" создаваться  в каждой иттерации,
              // тем самым можно разделить значения каждого обрабатываемого 
              // элемента "proc".
              var listCSV = [];

              // В текущем элементе "proc" выбираем все li-элементы 
              // и проходим по ним циклом.
              $(this).find("li").each(function(){

                  // Добавляем в listCSV текст из текущего li-элемента.
                  listCSV.push($(this).text());
              });

              // Преобразуем массив в строку вида "elem1","elem2","elem3"
              var values = '"'+listCSV.join('","')+'"';

              // Добавляем в элемент с классом "procChecker" скрытый элемент ввода.
              // Kвадратные скобки в его имени указывают на авто.создание массива 
              // на стороне сервера. Пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7880656/3129992
              $(".procChecker").append("<input type='hidden' name='prodstuff[]' value='+values+' />");

              // Вывод тестовых сообщений
              $("#output").append("<p>"+values+"</p>");
              console.debug(listCSV);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cпасибо за совет, я это учту и посмотрю, что можно сделать. По теме, функция работает, но мне нужно не только распечатать, но и сохранить массив, поэтому я использую `<input type="hidden" name="leader[]" class="hiddenListInput" />`, а затем `$(".hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);`, чтобы сохранить полученные данные, после использования вашего варианта сохраняется только последние данные с последней строки цикла. Как это можно исправить? Спасибо

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Если я правильно понял, Вы передаете в скрытых полях данные на сторону PHP сервера. Если так, то можно передавать скрытые поля с одинаковым именем (например,  `prodstuff[]`). Эти поля на стороне сервера автоматически преобразуются в массив. Ответ поправил.

Comment: Cпасибо большое за помощь. Все работает как надо, не могли бы Вы  прокоментировать код для более полного понимания. И что можно было бы изменить в моем коде? Что в нем не так? Спасибо за ответ, и прошу прощения за ужасный код, опыта не так много, буду пытаться сделать лучше. :) Upvote сделать не могу так как не хватает репутации. Спасибо.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Не поймите меня неправильно, но этот ресурс не предназначается для образовательных целей или его использования в качестве форума. Если у Вас возникают базовые вопросы относительно работы PHP или JavaScript, то советую Вам зарегистрироваться на тематических сайтах, например на http://www.php.su/ и http://javascript.ru/. На вышеуказанных ресурсах присутствуют статьи освещающие наиболее часто возникающие вопросы у людей, начинающих изучение web-программирования. P.S.: комментарии в код сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.